# SQLLocalDB.exe info - returns error code 15100, etc

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I'm trying to work on a version problem with LocalDB. The command "sqllocaldb i" seems to work.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqllocaldb i

MSSQLLocalDB

ProjectsV12

But, when I ask for something specific, I get only errors. (I'm on Windows 10)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB

FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15100

FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15105

FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15105

FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15105

FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15105

Comment: 15100 is `ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, 15105 is `ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_LOADED`. Both of these have to do with localizing messages and suggest that you may have a corrupt installation, or else a language setting that `sqllocaldb` really can't deal with for some reason.

Comment: Jeroen, thanks for the reply. After looking into it further, I found this:   https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36486376-sqllocaldb-utility-2016-returns-formatmessagew-fa  It looks like this is a bug in SQL Srever 2016 LocalDB that has never been fixed! What a disappointment.

Comment: There is LocalDB 2017 and LocalDB 2019 !?

Comment: Erik, thanks for the reply. If I install LocalDB 2017, will I be able to set the default instance to the 2016 version? I need to be on 2016 version because that's what my customers are using. Currently my default is v12.0 (2014 version), and if I try to restore a database backed up with v13.0 (2016 version), it doesn't work. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply Paul. I have also removed all older SQL installs, but to get information on a particular LocalDB server instance using the SqlLocalDB.exe utility, I had to install the 2017 version. For instance I can now get information on an instance of SQLLocalDB (2016 version) that I created and called 'TAS_LocalDB_V13' using the command -

SqlLocalDB i TAS_LocalDB_V13

But, since there are now two versions of SQLLocalDB installed, there are two executables named SqlLocalDB.exe. The one that will run depends on the system environment path variable. I had to edit the path variable so that the path to SqlLocalDB.exe appearing first in the list was the 2017 version (which works).

Note - even though the i command in 2016 version does not work, other important commands like 'c' to create a server instance do work.

Comment: Ugh, I just experienced this problem (don't know why I didn't see it at the time of my original post). So I agree that cleaning and re-installing 2016 does not completely fix this. Since I haven't installed any other versions, I think we can at least say this is specific to SQL 2016 and its updates, i.e., the other versions I uninstalled most likely had nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing all traces of SQL from my machine and re-installing only what I needed (2016 in my case). Basically, search for "SQL" in Control Panel and remove whatever shows up.

I think this has to do with having multiple versions installed, and/or corruption happening when you update them, because:

- I had SQL components ranging from 2008-2017 installed (both standard and express), and,
- the problem started happening right after I applied the latest cumulative updates, which were mainly for SQL 2016.

---

**UPDATE:** it looks like the fix for this is closer to: re-install 2016 and install the 2017 `sqllocaldb` - no need to clean up other versions as I did. See Victor's [subsequent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65622181/63209) as well as my comment there.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-installing as identified by @Paul, I found the resolution was to look at the system environment variable "Path" and I moved the paths associated with the latest version of SQLserver to be first in the list rather than later in the list.

You can verify the order using:

```
where.exe sqllocaldb
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe
```

Hope this saves someone some grief!