# I can't connect to my LocalDB (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB [2016]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-express, localdb

In my machine was installed several versions of `SQL Server 2008,2016,2019`, but in my current project I have to work only with 2016. I uninstalled 2019 version (because some times the file .mdf that I use to up to source code was generated on the wrong version [2019] and I couldn't find the reason, so I decided to uninstall 2019) after that I got error to accessing LocalDB.

Firstly the error said something like `Parenting to MSSQL15` I don't remember the exact error, but that make me think the DB was still pointing to 2019 so I uninstalled and reinstalled SQL Server 2016 and now I having another error.

In SSMS if I try to connect to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB I get:

> Cannot connect to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 0 -  [x89C50118]) (Microsoft SQL Server,
> Error: -1983577832)

If I go to CMD to see what I have as servers I get:

> C:\Users\rmarchetto>sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB ProjectsV13

But if I try to access specifically MSSQLLocalDB I get:

> C:\Users\rmarchetto>sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB Call to
> LocalDBFormatMessage failed. Error code returned:
> 2311389448. Error in LocalDBFormatMessage! Error code returned:
> 2311389454.

Comment: Is the LocalDB instance started?

Comment: Where I can verify that ? Than SQL Server Configuration Manager 2016 ? If Yes I can only see SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS), no option for LocalDB

Comment: Only to be more precise "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" is started on SQL Server 2016 Configuration Manager >SQL Server Configuration Manager (Local) > SQL Server Services

Comment: Config Manager doesn't support LocalDB.  You have to use the cmd line util sqllocaldb.exe.  Just run `sqllocaldb start` which will ensure that your LocalDB instance starts (if it can).

Comment: I have to execute "sqllocaldb start" on the same folder of "sqllocaldb.exe" ? Where it is placed ? I tried to execute the command here : C:\Users\rmarchetto>sqllocaldb start , and I got the same errors : "Call to LocalDBFormatMessage failed. Error code returned"

Comment: It should get set in your path so you can run it from anywhere.  If you got that error, then it ran and it looks like you have a problem with your LocalDB instance.

Comment: What u suggest me to do ? I have Uninstalled all my instances before installing again 2016 again

Comment: This may be of interest.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611620/sqllocaldb-exe-info-returns-error-code-15100-etc.  In other searches I'm also seeing an issue and the solution was to reinstall or upgrade.

Comment: I had found this answer before, so my option are : uninstall every thing related to SQL Server or install a new version of SQL instance to access LocalDB 2016 ?

Comment: I think it's more like upgrade to 2017

Comment: But the project that I'm working demands a LocalDB 2016

Comment: Well, then I would say try the reinstall.  Otherwise I'm not sure what to say.

Comment: It is unlikely your project demands something that is _precisely_ 2016. What evidence do you have that it wouldn't work with 2017 or 2019? Here's a guide for 2017 (that is valid for 2019 as well): https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5612/getting-started-with-sql-server-2017-express-localdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand

Comment: Is one of the requirement for the project

Comment: Who's requirement?  If you can demonstrate that you are running into a bug then I would think there would be the option to negotiate an upgrade.

Comment: That doesn't make it a valid or breaking requirement, but ok, reinstall.

Comment: I don't know precisely why they demand this version, I known that the others systems that are related to the project that I'm working with are on 2016 version and the first time that I delivered a Solution on 2019 they couldn't execute. May 2017 be more likely to works then 2019 ? When u say reinstall, is to do some thing different that I have done in my question ?

Comment: I deleted everything related to SQL Server, after I reinstalled only 2016r, I'm still having a issue with 2019: "The description for Event ID 527 from source SQLLocalDB 13.0 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event: 

MSSQL15E.LOCALDB

The resource loader failed to find MUI file"

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem, actually I don't known literally which keys u must delete but, to stop the problem of parenting to another SQL version I needed to go to "Registry Editor" and I deleted every key on :

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances

After that I was able to connect to my (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB [2016] without further errors =)

Comment: Very well. This solved the problem