# Unable to stop/delete a corrupted sqllocaldb instance

Tags: nunit, localdb

I'm having a strange issue with my SQLLocalDB, when I first started using it for a test case everything worked. When I ran it through a devops pipeline it failed saying "\datamodel.mdf" did not exist. I noticed that the DataDirectory was not working.

When I made a change to set the DataDirectory in my [TestSetup] method it worked a few times. However, suddenly I started getting an error during the test case saying "unable to create file xxx.mdf, file already exists". If I then copied the mdf file to a new name, it wouldwork for a period of time then start failing again.

Digging further I tried to cleanup the sqllocaldb but found I was unable to interact with it.

I ultimately found instructions to stop/delete the sql instance, but I found I was unable to do that either.

the "info" command shows the instance:

```
sqllocaldb i
MSSQLLocalDB
ProjectsV13
```

If i do info for the problem instance:

```
sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15100
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15105
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15105
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15105
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15105
```

stop also fails:

```
sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB -k
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15100
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this artice: [SQLLocalDB.exe info - returns error code 15100, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611620/sqllocaldb-exe-info-returns-error-code-15100-etc/75814435#75814435)

I found the solution to my problem, the problem with the MSSQLLocalDB is that the commandline tool was defaulting to an old version of the sql server, I updated my environment variable to make the latest version first in the "path" list and the command started working.

You can verify the order using:

```
where.exe sqllocaldb
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe
```

What started this whole investigation was that my devops pipeline was failing with an invalid path to the datadirectory. I ultimately found I had to set the DataDirectory in my test project which is what triggered the conflicts (still not completely sure why). To address this I modified by Unit test project to have a new "global" class that did the following:

1. on startup it will set the datadirectory to the AppDomain.BaseDirectory
2. on teardown it will "drop" the "database"

Here is my class definition:

```
namespace LNOSCMPortal.Unit.Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class GlobalActions
    {

        private string _baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            // set the data directory
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", _baseDir);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            // create connection to the sql local db
            var connStr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LNOSCMDataModel"].ConnectionString);
            var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr.ToString());
            try
            {
                // construct the dbname
                var dbname = connStr.AttachDBFilename.Replace("|DataDirectory|", _baseDir).ToUpper();
                conn.Open();
                // drop the local db so that future runs don't conflict
                var cmd = new SqlCommand($"use master;ALTER DATABASE [{dbname}] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; drop database [{dbname}]", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the app.config where i setup the connection:

```
<add name="DataModel" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;App=EntityFramework;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|DataModel.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And finally in my project, I selected BOTH the .mdf and the .ldf files and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always"